# QGIS: multiple values in a single field of the attribute table

Tags: qgis, shapefile, database

I am creating an archaeological map with a simple point shapefile. But I need to be able to enter multiple values in a single field of the attribute table. For example, an archaeological site can belong to different phases, in my case "Achaemenid" and "Sasanian". How do I do this thing, making sure that QGIS consider "Achaemenid" and "Sasanian" two different attributes even if they are in the same field?

Comment: A Field or column can have unlimited number of unique attribute values or may be controlled to a defined value list, can you elaborate more what you mean by "How do I do this thing, making sure that QGIS consider "Achaemenid" and "Sasanian" two different attributes even if they are in the same field?"?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? there are several *phases* available and each site can belong to one **or more** of the available *phases*.

Comment: Yes Matthias, that's exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Caveat: fairly new to qgis, so someone else may show up with a better answer)

I think there are a couple ways of addressing this requirement.  This answer is a little hazy because it's not clear exactly what you mean by "making sure that QGIS consider "Achaemenid" and "Sasanian" two different attributes...".

From a database-centric point of view, you would typically not try to store multiple values in a single field like this: you would instead have a mapping table that would map feature ids to phases, and then to find all the phases for a given feature you would perform a table join.  This is relatively easy if you're using a database backend like postgis or something, but doesn't really map well to the features available in a shapefile.

Another option is to use a simple text field and store your phases (e.g., as a comma delimited field), and then use `LIKE` queries for selecting/filtering/etc.  For example, to find all features with the "Achaemenid" phase:

```
"phases" LIKE '%Achaemenid%'
```

That works fine, but isn't necessarily going to be performant if you have thousands of features.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know if it's useful! Maybe my problem will be more clear if I explain one of my goals: I have to create a thematic map for every historical period in northwestern Afghanistan.
So, if for example I have City A built by Achaemenids and still living under the Sasanians, City B built by Achaemenids and with no trace of Sasanian occupation, and City C built by Sasanians, my "Achaemenid" map should show A and B but no C, while my "Sasanian" map should show A and C but no B.